# How to declare an MVC Model and WCF DataContract in one place?

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to create a 1-page site with knockout.js and MVC 4.

After making some changes the user will click a save button targeting the controller `Save` action.
Controller side I want to validate the input data.
If the data is valid - I need to call a WCF method.
If the data is not valid - I'll return something to the client side and tell them something like "first name is too long".

It's simple to make something like this:

- Declare `SiteModel` with DataAnnotations
- Declare controller action `public JsonResult Save(SiteModel data)`
- If the model is valid than create a new instance of the WCF DataContract and call a WCF method

Code:

```
public JsonResult Save(SiteModel data)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var ui =  WcfUserInfo{FirstName = data.FirstName};
        if(wcfclient.wcfmethod(ui))
            return Json("IsValid");
    }
    return Json("IsNotValid");
}
```

Is it possible to create a DataContract with DataAnnotations and use this DataContract in the `Save` method, something like `public JsonResult Save(WcfDataContract data)`?

I just don't want to create and support two different classes with the same data: one MVC Model and one WCF DataContract.

Thank you.

UPDATE:
this 2 posts resolve my problem. 
[Send objects with custom attributes via a wcf service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829976/send-objects-with-custom-attributes-via-a-wcf-service)
[How to make WCF client use the same data types as the WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2309969/how-to-make-wcf-client-use-the-same-data-types-as-the-wcf-service)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a counter point to **Anton**'s answer, which I do believe is a valid argument, I could argue that these two representations encompass exactly the same concern.  What is a *View Model* but a "*Data Contract*" between the client (the browser) and server (web server).  An *MVC View Model* and a *WCF Data Contract* both serve to establish a defined set of data that is communicated between two endpoints.  To that end, if your *WCF Service* and *Data Contract* exist solely to provide the Web Server and client (browser) with your application data than why not use the same representation.

I don't believe there is anything wrong, nor any conflict will arise, from tagging the same class with `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes along with DataAnnotation attributes such as; `Required`, `Range`, `Display`, etc.

```
[DataContract]
public class SiteModel
{
    [DataMember]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }


    [DataMember]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

To reiterate, I am NOT saying that **Anton** is wrong.  I am simply stating an alternative perspective as I believe the question is one of opinion more so than one that has a right and wrong answer.

Comment: I try to created DataContract with [StringLength(50)]. Then I addad to my client service reference to WCF test project. There were generated property without [StringLength(50)]. What can you advise to me?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is **NOT** what you want to hear, but I cannot stress this enough:
*Your data contract with the service and your view model (your JSON representation) should not be the same*. They are separate concerns, even though it does not feel like that right now.

Given that, what is stopping you from simply replacing the `SiteModel` with `WcfUserInfo` if they are the same (i.e. have the same properties)?

PS. If you use AutoMapper, you don't have to do the mapping yourself, AutoMapper will take care of that for you with two lines of code: one to configure the map and one to execute the mapping.

Comment: asymptoticFault is right. there is 2 endpoints. web server part is just an interlayer. I want to use it like a simple server validator. Check something simple, like a firstname length. And i don't want to create a copy of datacontract with DataAnnotation attrebutes.